# Full details of user using linked in OAuth in ios8

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, xcode6

I am unable to get full detail of user using linked in OAuth in ios8. I want to retrieve birthdate and all other detail.

I have used this url to get full linked in user profile.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[@"https://api.linkedin.com" stringByAppendingString:@"/v1/people/~:(id,first-name,last-name,maiden-name,formatted-name,phonetic-last-name,location:(country:(code)),industry,distance,current-status,current-share,network,skills,phone-numbers,date-of-birth,main-address,positions:(title),educations:(school-name,field-of-study,start-date,end-date,degree,activities))"]];
```

I have used OAuthStarterKit for login with linked in.

Comment: What have you tried? What happens with your request? An error message? Partial data? No data? You've given very little for anyone to go on.

Comment: I am getting response and all the things working properly, but though I have set full profile permission I am not getting birthdate, gender like those fields.